# Return the value of a 2D PDF given x and y in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, indexing, histogram

I have some data that I plotted the PDF using matplotlib's hist2D function.
The result looks like this:

[image]

The hist2d function returns a triple of arrays: H,xedges,yedges. H being the 2D histogram value.
Now I'd like to turn this discrete H matrix and turn it into a function, that returns the value of H for any given (x,y) input. 
In other words I'd like to turn my 2D histogram into a 2D step function. Is there a specific function that would be computationally cheap that I could use on that purpose?

This looks like a pretty simple operation (usually done for image processing but with pixel indices instead of real numbers) but I'm unable to find anything about it, can you please help me?

Comment: Perhaps a bivariate normal pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution it just has some rotation and scaling which can be accounted for using the standard deviations in the X and Y.  The pdf is easy to generate, I have don't the reverse by generating your graph from correlation coefficient and X and Y descriptive statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an interpolator from the counts like this:

```
from numpy import random, histogram2d, diff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

# Generate sample data
n = 10000
x = random.randn(n)
y = -x + random.randn(n)

# bin
nbins = 100
H, xedges, yedges = histogram2d(x, y, bins=nbins)

# Figure out centers of bins
def centers(edges):
    return edges[:-1] + diff(edges[:2])/2

xcenters = centers(xedges)
ycenters = centers(yedges)

# Construct interpolator
pdf = interp2d(xcenters, ycenters, H)

# test
plt.pcolor(xedges, yedges, pdf(xedges, yedges))
```

Result:

[image: result of interpolation]

Note that this will be linearly interpolated rather than step-wise. For a quicker version which assumes a regular grid, this will also work:

```
from numpy import meshgrid, vectorize

def position(edges, value):
    return int((value - edges[0])/diff(edges[:2]))

@vectorize
def pdf2(x, y):
    return H[position(yedges, y), position(xedges, x)]

# test - note we need the meshgrid here to get the right shapes
xx, yy = meshgrid(xcenters, ycenters)
plt.pcolor(xedges, yedges, pdf2(xx, yy))
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.